# GitHub: Accept Pull Request, But Only Some Commits

Tags: git, github

Say you've got a user who made a few commits and rolled them into one pull request.  You want to accept one of the commits, but reject the others.  Is this possible with GitHub?

Comment: This is more of a Git activity than GitHub.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can manually accept certain commits using `git-cherry-pick` and then close the pull request.

- https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

Answer (score 25):

Next to the "Merge pull request" button, there should be a "Use the command line" link to instructions on how to do it manually. You should follow these instructions (create new local branch and pull in their changes), but then instead of merging that whole branch back into master, you just cherry-pick the commits you want.

e.g. to review a pull request from user: jashkenas, in their branch: new-feature

```
git checkout -b jashkenas-new-feature master
git pull https://github.com/jashkenas/YOUR_REPO_NAME.git new-feature
```

And then do your testing, and then when you're ready:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH_1
git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH_2
# etc
git push origin master
```

Comment: I think when we `cherry-pick` a commit, it merges that commit into master? What if there are conflicts, would it prompt to resolve those?

Comment: @eMAD if you're going to be dealing with conflicts, it's probably easier to do an interactive rebase on the feature branch, and drop the other commits and handle any conflicts there, and then merge that branch into master.